# How to manipulate HTML data that comes from the server using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this data that comes from the server:

```
const userInfo = getUserInfo(); //Returns: <span class="info">His name is Sam</span><span class="info">He is 20 years old</span><span class="info">He is from Spain</span><span class="info">He is fluent in English</span>
```

Then, there are two react components. The first one, ListInfo, shows all of the user info and if the second component, ShowMore, is added to the page, the ListInfo should have to show only the first two pieces of information.

```
class ListInfo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      const info = this.props.info; 
      <div className="ListInfo">
        {info}
        <ShowMore items={info} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ShowMore extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDisplayingAll: true
    };

    this.handleDisplaying = this.handleDisplaying.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isDisplayingAll: false
    });
  }

  handleDisplaying(e) {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleDisplaying}>
        {this.state.isDisplayingAll ? 'Less' : 'More'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ListInfo info={userInfo} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

So here comes the questions:

Firstly, react documents say that you should add a key property if you're rendering items of lists, and the info that comes from the server is a list. So how could I add a key to them? I mean, do I have to write some code to add a key to each item?

Secondly, I should not change the `props` that a component gets, so how should I change the style of the DOM elements (the last two ones)?

Thirdly, would elements having `class` instead of `className` make a problem in rendering?

Comment: I've never seen using `class` instead of `className` lead to problems, but the rationale is that class is a reserved keyword in JS (of which JSX is an extension). You'll get an ugly warning

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to set up your backend to serve the data as JSON. Then you can write out the JSX to avoid the problems with syntax differences.

If you are absolutely constrained to HTML for some reason, I've had success using [react-magic](https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm) in the past to translate the HTML into JSX. I think I have a webpack loader lying around here somewhere if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a disconnect between JSX, what React uses, and actual HTML.  Even though React looks to be using HTML inside of JS, it's actually using some compiler tricks to turn the HTML into JS statements. This explains your first question and third question.

Take a look at this page for what is actually happening under the hood of React.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

There is a way to use the HTML returned back from the server directly in a component. I would read over the Docs here to see how to do it and what are the pros and cons of doing so.
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Normally components expose a style prop that allows you to override the default style. I would look into the docs to see if the components you are wanting to style have a style prop.